# How to automate and generalize the following command -when used into a bash script- for different parameters and values?

Tags: bash, loops, echo

I want to use this command into a bash script where each time I will have a different array input containing the parameters?

knowing that I have an array (as input from the user) where each column contains `"parameteri=valuei"`.

I want to get rid of the hardcoded aspect in introducing the name and the value of each parameter.

For instance, with this input:

```
"id=123,verbosity=high"
```

I will eventually get this final instruction:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --user USER:TOKEN \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'
```

What is a clean way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it the sexy way, building the jsonParameters from specified `key=value parameters`:

```
#!/bin/bash

jsonParameters=""
while IFS=',' read -r -a parameterEntries; do
  for parameterEntry in "${parameterEntries[@]}"; do
    IFS='=' read -r key value <<< "$parameterEntry"
    [ ! -z "$jsonParameters" ] && jsonParameters="$jsonParameters,"
    jsonParameters="$jsonParameters {\"name\":\"$key\", \"value\": \"$value\"}"
  done
done <<< "$@"
```

Explanations:

- the first loop will create the array named parameterEntries, with all your specified parameters, each element will contain `key=value`
- then, the second loop, which iterates on each element of this array, will extract key, and value of it
- eventually, it is only syntax writting to get the JSON output you want
- the `[ ! -z "$jsonParameters" ] && jsonParameters="$jsonParameters,"` is just here to add a separating coma, only if there is more than one element

Then you simply have to use the `$jsonParameters` where you want:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --user USER:TOKEN \
  --data-urlencode json="{\"parameter\": [$jsonParameters]}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Bsquare, can you elaborate a quick explanation?

Comment: I added explanations in my answer.

Comment: Good, so I was right when I got rid of the first loop because I already handled the array containing the parameters. Thanks man I appreciate it.